# Temporary SWF files to use during Web Development?

Tags: resources, flash, temporary

Does anyone know of a site where I can download temporary SWF files to use as placeholders during web development? I've searched a lot on Google and can't dig anything up like this?

Was wondering if there is something similar to what http://placehold.it is for PNGs, but just need soemthing for SWFs.

I'd like to just grab one and use it to drop into my code, so all the Flash designer has to do is just replace the temporary SWF with the one that's going to be used on the live site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go: http://clearmpls.com/temp/placeholder/

Source files: http://clearmpls.com/temp/placeholder/placeholder.zip

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. Is there anyway to set the background and font color that appears in the SWF via params?

Comment: sure - I just updated the files above. There's a javascript param called bg_color now.

Comment: Thanks -- although I'm not seeing any difference. (Are you sure the files were updated?) Is there anyway to change the font color too?

Comment: it's in there - it didn't update for me in chrome, but I think it's cause the swf is cached. Download again and that version lets you define both txt and bg colors.

Comment: That was the problem -- it was cached in Chrome. I see the new parameter for txt_color but it doesn't seem to change (even after clearing the cache). Also, what does the "0x" mean in the color "0xFF0000"?

Comment: that's a hex color in Flash - same as HTML, just with 0x in front. Yeah, not sure why it's not picking up in Chrome properly. Works all around though. You can also manually change the color in the .as file and republish the swf.

Comment: The size in the SWF is showing 0x0 in IE, but works in all other browsers. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, yeah - realized I populated the textfield before the resize - maybe it'll work now. Give it a shot.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks dude. You rock!

Comment: no prob - never thought there'd be a need for something like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have your flash designer make one. It would take literally 10 seconds.

Comment: +1 30 sec. if you want it to look exactly like the png placeholder, displaying whatever size you set in the html page.

Comment: Yep. You don't even need a designer, or a paid copy of Flash. Just download the demo, and use it to create a new project at the resolution you want. Add one of those placeholder pngs to the stage, export the .swf, and you're done.